# Serve an opencpu app on an ipv4 address in a windows environment

Tags: r, opencpu

The way opencpu "productionnise" an app is to get your own linux server then to install your package and then launch your app.

Before that, I am still in a dev environment, where I work on a windows machine.

I would like to run the app locally behind a firewall and send the ipv4 link of my machine to a collegue, to allow him to test my app, using my machine as a server.

Is there a way to serve my app on the Ipv4 address of my windows machine?

From what I understand, on a windows machine, the adviced architecture would be more to use a vm to emulate a linux server. But if there is a way to avoid it, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a local OpenCPU server via `opencpu::ocpu_start_server()`, which uses port 5656 by default. If you then point your browser to `http://<your-ip>:5656/ocpu`, you will be greeted with the normal OpenCPU interface.